# C++20 Concept/requires with std::map emplace not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm experimenting a bit with c++20 concepts and requires, and tried to make a concept that checks valid parameters for a `std::map` `emplace` call.
Very similar for example as at [C++20 concepts how to define existence of a function with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058820/c20-concepts-how-to-define-existence-of-a-function-with-arguments) but then with the emplace function at std::map.
However this concept does not work as I would expect: on a `map<string, string>` it succeeds with (int, string) parameters, see example.
What is going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <map>


template<typename Tobj, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
concept Check = requires (Tobj obj, TVal1 val1, TVal2 val2)
{
    obj.emplace(val1,val2);
};

int main(int, char **)
{  
    std::map<std::string, std::string> map;
    std::cout << Check<decltype(map), std::string, std::string>;        // prints 1, as expected.
    std::cout << Check<decltype(map), int, std::string>;                // prints 1 but would expect 0 don't understand?!
    //        map.emplace(1, std::string("Hello"));                         // because this obviously fails to compile
        
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `map::emplace()` is *not* a constrained function, the expression  `obj.emplace(...)` in the `requires`-clause is always valid, as hard errors only happen in the function body.

You may need to additionally check whether the value type of the container can be constructed from arguments

```
template<typename Container, typename... Args>
concept container_emplacable = 
  std::ranges::input_range<Container> &&
  std::constructible_from<std::ranges::range_value_t<Container>, Args...> &&
  requires(Container& c, Args&&... args) {
    requires (requires { c.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } ||         // for map::emplace
              requires { c.emplace(c.end(), std::forward<Args>(args)...); }); // for vector::emplace
  };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fs9PxaG5b)

Let me briefly explain the seemingly crazy syntax above, which can be split into the structure of `requires { requires (requires A || requires B); }`. The nested `require` requires that the expression `(requires A || requires B)` evaluates to `true` to satisfy the concept, while `requires A` and `requires B` respectively detect whether `A` and `B` are valid expressions.

Comment: That'd be called a defect in std. Why would they add a feature and not use it?

Comment: @Red.Wave These functions all have *Preconditions* that require argument types to meet *Cpp17EmplaceConstructible*.

Comment: @#$& that's the doc. Requirements must be expressed as code. The keyword `requires` serves that purpose; it was adpted as part of `concept` light addition to C++20. So they should've constrained the STL classes by now. Sorry, for some unknown reasons, I cannot type your eastern ID.

Comment: @Red.Wave it is the same with other 'perfect forward to constructor' functions like `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`. Personally I wished, that the C++ standard commitee would focus more on integration of new language features in older parts of the library.

Comment: @康桓瑋 the typing issue is somehow gone now

Comment: @JakobStark that's a real problem. There's no centralized integration of standards in iso. The similarities in semantics of `any`, `optional` and `varaint` is opposing their none-conforming interfaces. A lot of abominations to the language could've been avoided.